# How to use variable in double cortisone in android

Tags: android

Please help me.
I need use variable in "" but I can't do it.

I have code for put date and time in a String.

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

and I have a code to make a file

```
String backupDBPath = "/SVprojects/DibaDb.back";
```

I want use `currentDateTimeString`  variable as file name but I get tired.

```
String backupDBPath = "/SVprojects/ 'currentDateTimeString' ";

 String backupDBPath = "/SVprojects/ currentDateTimeString  ";
```

Comment: You need to give us more detail to work with. What language and system are you using, what faults are you getting and so on. Perhaps you will then get some answers.

Comment: In Java you can use String.format() method to replace/insert Strings : String.format ("Hello %s","World");